# Simple Injector: RegisterInitializer does not always fire

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, ioc-container, simple-injector

I use the `RegisterInitializer` method to inject properties in base types as follows:

```
container.RegisterInitializer<BaseHandler>(handler =>
{
    handler.Context = container.GetInstance<HandlerContext>();
});
```

This works great, but the `RegisterInitializer` doesn't get fired on all registered types that inherit from BaseHandler. It doesn't seem to run when I call `new` myself:

```
var url = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NotificationServiceUrl"];
container.Register<Handler<NotifyCustomerMessage>>(() => 
    new NotifyCustomerHandler(url));

// many other Handler<T> lines here
```

Why is that, and how can I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

This behavior has changed in *Simple Injector 2*: Initializers will now also fire on `Func<T>` registrations. The reason is that Simple Injector now has explicit lifestyle support and now in fact behaves like StructureMap (as described below).

---

Your observation is correct. The Simple Injector documentation [describes](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20the%20Simple%20Injector&referringTitle=Home&ProjectName=simpleinjector#Configuring_Property_Injection) it like this:

> Note: The container will not be able
>   to call an initializer delegate on a
>   type that is manually constructed
>   using the `new` operator. Use automatic
>   constructor injection whenever
>   possible.

The best way to overcome this problem is allowing Simple Injector to use automatic constructor injection.

Your `NotifyCustomerHandler` takes a `string` constructor argument, which makes it impossible to do automatic constructor injection. Your `NotifyCustomerHandler` seems to have [multiple responsibilities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Abstract the notification service from the handler functionality, by hiding this service behind an `INotificationService` interface and letting the handler depend on that interface. You can than inject that configuration value into the notification service.

***Some background information on why Simple Injector behaves this way***

Although other DI frameworks (such as [StructureMap](http://structuremap.net/structuremap/) with its `OnCreationForAll` method) will invoke the delegate even when you new up a type, Simple Injector does not. It is caused by the difference in which the frameworks expect users to register lifestyle.

With StructureMap, lifestyles are configured by explicitly calling the `LifecycleIs` method. With Simple Injector users are expected to configure lifestyles by registering delegates that implement lifestyle themselves. Look for instance at the [Per Thread lifestyle example](http://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ObjectLifestyleManagement#PerThread) in the documentation. With StructureMap it is the framework that controls the lifetime for you, while with Simple Injector it is often up to the user.

In other words, StructureMap expects a registered delegate to always create a new instance, while Simple Injector does not have this expectation. Because StructureMap expects a new instance is returned, it can safely initialize that object after calling the delegate. Caching of instances is done elsewhere. Simple Injector however, will *not* call an initializer on objects returned from such delegate, simply because that would possibly reinitialize the same object over and over again, which could cause unexpected application behavior and possible performance problems.

I hope this helps.